Python: compare csv files and print similarities
I need to compare two csv files and print out their similarities. The first file has names and concentrations and the second is like a "best" list with just names and I need to graph the similarities.
For example, this is how my lists looks like:
file1-old_file.csv
name_id,   conc_test1,  conc_test2
name1,     #### ,        ####
name2,     ####,        ####
...

etc..
file2-best_choice_file.csv
name_id
name1
name2
...

I know this isn't the best way, but this was how I was trying:
file1 = pd.read_csv('old_file.csv')
file2 = pd.read_csv('best_choice_file.csv')
common_rows = pd.merge(file1, file2)
print("common rows:")
print(common_rows)

This results in a MergeError.  If anyone could help me out I would truly appreciate it!!

This results in a MergeError It might help if you posted the entire error, so we can see the specific cause.

So this is what I found that works for me:
df_final = pd.merge(file1, file2, on=['name_id'])

df_final.to_excel("sample_output.xlsx")

